# How to create a function inside a structure in a header file and implement this function in another c source file?

Tags: c++, struct, function-pointers, function-call

Here I created a main.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
struct person_t a;
int main()
{
    a.func(1,2);
}
```

And I have a header called "Header.h", I define a structure in this file

```
struct person_t {
    char name;
    unsigned age;
    int(*func)(int, int);
};
```

Then I implement `int(*func)(int, int);` in another c file called "Source.c"

```
#include "Header1.h"
struct person_t a;
int add2(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
};

a.func = &add2;
```

But it seems not work, does anyone who has any idea of this question?

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "not work". Provide the specific error or incorrect behaviour you observe. But for starters, `a.func = &add2;` is invalid C as non-initialiser assignment statements must be inside a function.

Comment: `struct person_t a;` in 2 different compilation units (files) are 2 different variables. `a.func = &add2;` can't exist outside of a function body.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will describe more detail about what behaviour I observe.
And finally I just solved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use statements outside a function like this

```
a.func = &add2;
```

Remove this statement and this declaration

```
struct person_t a;
```

from `Source.c`.

In the header place the function declaration

```
int add2(int x, int y);
```

And in the file with main write

```
int main()
{
    struct person_t a;
    a.func = add2;

    a.func(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just solved it